# Angular - Update data automatically without Refresh the Page

Tags: javascript, ajax, angular, typescript, dynamic

In my application there is a table that get rows from database.

This is the AJAX CALL **(SERVICE)**

```
getPosts(): Observable<Posts[]> {
    return this.http.post<Posts[]>(this.myAppUrl + this.myApiPostsUrl, this.authService.getLoggedUserFromSessionStorage())
      .pipe(
        retry(1),
        catchError(this.errorHandler)
      );
  }
```

All work perfectly, but my datas dont update automatically, and the user need to refresh the page to see the new rows, how can i do this?
I would like do that the new rows are added in the table dynamically ... without update the page.
This is the table

**COMPONENT HTML**

```
    <table *ngIf="(posts$ | async)?.length>0" class="table align-items-center table-flush">
    .....
 <tr *ngFor="let post of (posts$ | async) | filter:authService.filter | paginate: config | orderBy: key : reverse">
              <!--              <td>{{posts.id}}</td>-->
              <td>{{post.title}}</td>
              <td>{{post.body}}</td>
.....
    </table>
```

**COMPONENT TS**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.loadPosts();
  }

  loadPosts() {
    this.message = 'Loading....';
    this.posts$ = this.postService.getPosts();
    if (this.posts$ == null) {
      this.message = 'No Posts found';
    }
  }
```

Thanks so much.

Comment: can you show the code of the filter you are using

Comment: in this case, you can either re-fetch the data from the server, or upon a successful post request, modify your posts property

Comment: @C_Ogoo I thought the same thing, but i dont know how to code this. I have to re-fetch every tot sec te data.

Comment: @PkSharmaPokhrel It's a string taken from the search module through a service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several options. Here is a reactive way of handling this. Any time `getPosts` is successful, you'll need to refetch the initial data.

To fetch your initial data you will need to wrap your `posts$` observable in an action stream:

```js
// create a stream for your post request
private readonly postAction$ = new Subject();

posts$ = this.postAction$.pipe(
  startWith(''),
  concatMap(()=> {
    return this.postService.getPosts(); // this will be your http get request
  }),
)
```

The `startWith` operator will cause your `get` request to fire initially without an observable been passed to your `postAction` observable.

Your `getPosts` method now will call `this.postAction$.next()` on success, that will trigger the refetch of your `posts$` observable.

```js
getPosts(): Observable<Posts[]> {
    return this.http.post<Posts[]>(this.myAppUrl + this.myApiPostsUrl, this.authService.getLoggedUserFromSessionStorage())
      .pipe(
        retry(1),
        catchError(this.errorHandler),
        tap(() => this.postAction$.next())
      );
  }
```

You can see a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-action-stream-post) of this. Check the console, you'll see that the `get` request is fired every time the button is clicked.

---

**With Interval**

```js
posts$ = interval(30000)
    .pipe(
      startWith(''),
      switchMap(() => return this.postService.getPosts();)
    )
```

Interval [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-posts-interval)

Comment: Thanks so much, but how dont know what write in return of('') .

Comment: With 'return of('string')' return ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object 'my data' of type 'string'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: You will replace `of(...` with your original get request. Could you add your code for your `posts$` observable and ill update the answer

Comment: i tried of(this.postsService.getPosts) but return error, the code is UP thanks so much.

Comment: Why in my back end there are always query and in angular all refresh every milliseconds? Could be a problem of memory and performance in my back end and front end , should be good if every 30-40 sec angular get new result ...

Comment: Everytime you update your backend with the `getPosts` method, the code will make a request to your backend to get the new data. The only other way to do this would be to do add to your posts array manually

Comment: I dont understand, i call your method (the only place with getPosts) only in ngOnInit of the component, its impossible set a interval ?

Comment: Its tied to another observable. so any time that observable emits, it will get called again. thats what `this.postAction$` that does

Comment: This method is ok for few users, but already with modest use, this code is not good, because freeze the backend ... is possible for you post a code with a interval, every 30 seconds for example?

Comment: Thanks so much, i did the same , but i have the little problem that the first time have to wait 30 sec to fetch data, so i created a other method with the same code of my post up, without RxJS, if i call all 2 in ngoninit(), dont work, the user have to wait always 30 sec like my method dont exist, what do you advice to me? I saw ngAfterViewCheck() ....

Comment: updated answer to solve that. `startWith` operator helps

Answer (score 0):

in Angular, when you want to update your html, you need to use ngFor to update your data automatically.

```
<table *ngIf="(posts$ | async)?.length>0" class="table align-items-center table-flush">
   <div *ngFor="let data of datas; let i = index>
      {{ data }}
   </div>
</table>
```

ngFor will loop on datas and update it when it changes

Comment: I did already (code up), but angular get all only when load the component.

Comment: Which hook did you implemented ? OnInit ?